# Check if textbox has changed. If so, update field.

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a textbox named "discount".
And a table called "PriceTable" which has dynamically added rows (). Inside each row is a td with the classname/ID "discountField". When Discount changes, each discount field must change to reflect this. I can do the logic fine, but how do I cycle through each box and append values?

so far I have:

```
 $(function () {
        var content = $('#discount').val();

        $('#discount').keyup(function () {
            if ($('#emp_discount').val() != content) {
                content = $('#emp_discount').val();
                //Change detected at discount - Add validation too


                $('#discountField').each(function () {
                    //dostuff alert("test");
                });


                //end discount

            }
        });
    });
```

This lets me find out when the field is changed. but not sure about changing the values.

This is a snippet of the table.

```
<tr class="row" onmouseover="this.className='row_selected">
                        <td>1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            £0
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            £100000
                        </td>
                        <td>0.0035 %
                        </td>
                        <td id="discountField">
                            1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

`

Comment: Just wondering is it some sort of e-commerce application? Because changing prices on front-end is very dangerous in any payment application.

Comment: Similar, but the prices never get passed to anywhere. No danger of script changing :)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things

(1) Do you have multiple rows with the discountField column? If so then you should consider setting the class instead of id to discountField

```
<td class="discountField">
                        1
</td>
```

(2) To set the value of the column you would do

```
$('.discountField').each(function () {
                $(this).html(content)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When cycling just use this

```
$("#discountField").html("new value");
```

If you want it recalculated you just insert the calculated new value.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. What if I wanted to use the value from the TD to it's left to change the value though? I just dont understand how i can do it without changing every box with the same value.

Comment: Unless I apply an ID to the row. And then possibly lookup ID/Class within the row??